# Why is my character either hovering or falling through the floor?

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, ogre, jmonkeyengine

I'm making a simple 3D scene with a character and a floor but the character is hovering, or falling through the scene if I put the y coordinate to a negative.

```
private void createCharacters() {
    CapsuleCollisionShape capsule = new CapsuleCollisionShape(3f, 4f);
    character = new CharacterControl(capsule, 0.01f);
    model = (Node) assetManager.loadModel("Models/Ninja/Ninja.mesh.xml");
    float scale = 0.25f;
    model.scale(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
    model.addControl(character);
    character.setPhysicsLocation(new Vector3f(0, -0.15f, 0));
    model.setShadowMode(ShadowMode.CastAndReceive);
    character.setViewDirection(new Vector3f(1, 0, 0));
    rootNode.attachChild(model);
    getPhysicsSpace().add(character);

}
```

The above code makes the character fall through the scene. Changing it just a little bit to this makes the character hover:

`character.setPhysicsLocation(new Vector3f(0, -0.09f, 0));`

[image]

If you want to inspect all of the code it's here

```
package adventure;

import java.applet.Applet;
import com.jme3.math.Quaternion;
import com.jme3.math.FastMath;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.jme3.material.RenderState.FaceCullMode;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import com.jme3.renderer.queue.RenderQueue.ShadowMode;
import com.jme3.animation.AnimChannel;
import com.jme3.animation.AnimControl;
import com.jme3.animation.AnimEventListener;
import com.jme3.animation.LoopMode;
import com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication;
import com.jme3.asset.BlenderKey;
import com.jme3.asset.TextureKey;
import com.jme3.asset.plugins.ZipLocator;
import com.jme3.bullet.BulletAppState;
import com.jme3.bullet.PhysicsSpace;
import com.jme3.bullet.collision.PhysicsCollisionEvent;
import com.jme3.bullet.collision.PhysicsCollisionListener;
import com.jme3.bullet.collision.shapes.CapsuleCollisionShape;
import com.jme3.bullet.collision.shapes.CollisionShape;
import com.jme3.bullet.collision.shapes.SphereCollisionShape;
import com.jme3.bullet.control.CharacterControl;
import com.jme3.bullet.control.RigidBodyControl;
import com.jme3.bullet.util.CollisionShapeFactory;
import com.jme3.effect.ParticleEmitter;
import com.jme3.effect.ParticleMesh.Type;
import com.jme3.effect.shapes.EmitterSphereShape;
import com.jme3.input.ChaseCamera;
import com.jme3.input.KeyInput;
import com.jme3.input.controls.ActionListener;
import com.jme3.input.controls.KeyTrigger;
import com.jme3.light.DirectionalLight;
import com.jme3.material.Material;
import com.jme3.math.ColorRGBA;
import com.jme3.math.Vector2f;
import com.jme3.math.Vector3f;
import com.jme3.post.FilterPostProcessor;
import com.jme3.post.filters.BloomFilter;
import com.jme3.renderer.Camera;
import com.jme3.renderer.queue.RenderQueue.ShadowMode;
import com.jme3.scene.Geometry;
import com.jme3.scene.Node;
import com.jme3.scene.Spatial;
import com.jme3.scene.shape.Box;
import com.jme3.scene.shape.Sphere;
import com.jme3.scene.shape.Sphere.TextureMode;
import com.jme3.system.AppSettings;
import com.jme3.system.JmeCanvasContext;
import com.jme3.terrain.geomipmap.TerrainLodControl;
import com.jme3.terrain.geomipmap.TerrainQuad;
import com.jme3.terrain.heightmap.AbstractHeightMap;
import com.jme3.terrain.heightmap.ImageBasedHeightMap;
import com.jme3.texture.Texture;
import com.jme3.texture.Texture.WrapMode;
import com.jme3.util.SkyFactory;

public class MountainWorld extends SimpleApplication implements ActionListener,
        PhysicsCollisionListener, AnimEventListener, Playable {






      /** Prepare Materials */
      Material wall_mat;
      Material stone_mat;
      Material floor_mat;

      /** Prepare geometries and physical nodes for bricks and cannon balls. */
      private RigidBodyControl    brick_phy;
      private static final Box    box;
      private RigidBodyControl    ball_phy;
      private static final Sphere sphere;
      private RigidBodyControl    floor_phy;
      private static final Box    floor;

      /** dimensions used for bricks and wall */
      private static final float brickLength = 0.48f;
      private static final float brickWidth  = 0.24f;
      private static final float brickHeight = 0.12f;

      static {
        /** Initialize the cannon ball geometry */
        sphere = new Sphere(32, 32, 0.4f, true, false);
        sphere.setTextureMode(TextureMode.Projected);
        /** Initialize the brick geometry */
        box = new Box(Vector3f.ZERO, brickLength, brickHeight, brickWidth);
        box.scaleTextureCoordinates(new Vector2f(1f, .5f));
        /** Initialize the floor geometry */
        floor = new Box(Vector3f.ZERO, 10f, 0.1f, 5f);
        floor.scaleTextureCoordinates(new Vector2f(3, 6));
      }







    private static World world;
    private static Person person;
    private static Player dplayer;
    private static TextArea textarea;
    private BulletAppState bulletAppState;
    private AnimChannel channel;
    private AnimControl control;
    // character
    CharacterControl character;
    Node model;
    // temp vectors
    Vector3f walkDirection = new Vector3f();
    // terrain
    TerrainQuad terrain;
    RigidBodyControl terrainPhysicsNode;
    // Materials
    Material matRock;
    Material matBullet;
    // animation
    AnimChannel animationChannel;
    AnimChannel shootingChannel;
    AnimControl animationControl;
    float airTime = 0;
    // camera
    boolean left = false, right = false, up = false, down = false;
    ChaseCamera chaseCam;
    // bullet
    Sphere bullet;
    SphereCollisionShape bulletCollisionShape;
    // explosion
    ParticleEmitter effect;
    // brick wall
    Box brick;
    float bLength = 0.8f;
    float bWidth = 0.4f;
    float bHeight = 0.4f;
    FilterPostProcessor fpp;
    private Spatial sceneModel;

    private RigidBodyControl landscape;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AppSettings settings = new AppSettings(true);
                settings.setWidth(850);
                settings.setHeight(440);

                MountainWorld canvasApplication = new MountainWorld();
                canvasApplication.setSettings(settings);
                canvasApplication.createCanvas(); // create canvas!
                JmeCanvasContext ctx = (JmeCanvasContext) canvasApplication
                        .getContext();
                ctx.setSystemListener(canvasApplication);
                Dimension dim = new Dimension(640, 480);
                ctx.getCanvas().setPreferredSize(dim);

                JFrame window = new JFrame("Mountain World");
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // a panel
                world = new DungeonWorld(canvasApplication);
                person = new Person(world, "You", null);
                dplayer = new Player(world, person);
                Commands commands = new Commands(person);
                textarea = new TextArea("", 10, 60,
                        TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
                textarea.append("You are in a mountain. The trolls live here.\n");
                textarea.setEditable(false);
                panel.add("West", ctx.getCanvas());
                panel.add("East", commands);
                panel.add("South", textarea);
                window.add(panel);
                window.pack();
                window.setVisible(true);
                canvasApplication.startCanvas();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
        bulletAppState = new BulletAppState();
        bulletAppState.setThreadingType(BulletAppState.ThreadingType.PARALLEL);
        stateManager.attach(bulletAppState);
        setupKeys();
        //prepareBullet();
        //prepareEffect();
        createLight();
        //createSky();
        initMaterials();
        initFloor();
        //createTerrain();
        //createWall();
        createCharacters();
        setupChaseCamera();
        setupAnimationController();
        setupFilter();
    }
     /** Make a solid floor and add it to the scene. */
      public void initFloor() {
        Geometry floor_geo = new Geometry("Floor", floor);
        floor_geo.setMaterial(floor_mat);
        floor_geo.setLocalTranslation(0, -0.1f, 0);
        this.rootNode.attachChild(floor_geo);
        /* Make the floor physical with mass 0.0f! */
        floor_phy = new RigidBodyControl(0.0f);
        floor_geo.addControl(floor_phy);
        bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace().add(floor_phy);
      }

      /** Initialize the materials used in this scene. */
      public void initMaterials() {
        wall_mat = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        TextureKey key = new TextureKey("Textures/Terrain/BrickWall/BrickWall.jpg");
        key.setGenerateMips(true);
        Texture tex = assetManager.loadTexture(key);
        wall_mat.setTexture("ColorMap", tex);

        stone_mat = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        TextureKey key2 = new TextureKey("Textures/Terrain/Rock/Rock.PNG");
        key2.setGenerateMips(true);
        Texture tex2 = assetManager.loadTexture(key2);
        stone_mat.setTexture("ColorMap", tex2);

        floor_mat = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        TextureKey key3 = new TextureKey("Textures/Terrain/Pond/Pond.jpg");
        key3.setGenerateMips(true);
        Texture tex3 = assetManager.loadTexture(key3);
        tex3.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        floor_mat.setTexture("ColorMap", tex3);
      }


    private void setupFilter() {
        FilterPostProcessor fpp = new FilterPostProcessor(assetManager);
        BloomFilter bloom = new BloomFilter(BloomFilter.GlowMode.Objects);
        fpp.addFilter(bloom);
        viewPort.addProcessor(fpp);
    }

    private PhysicsSpace getPhysicsSpace() {
        return bulletAppState.getPhysicsSpace();
    }

    private void setupKeys() {
        inputManager.addMapping("wireframe", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_T));
        inputManager.addListener(this, "wireframe");
        inputManager.addMapping("CharLeft", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_A));
        inputManager.addMapping("CharRight", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_D));
        inputManager.addMapping("CharUp", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_W));
        inputManager.addMapping("CharDown", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_S));
        inputManager.addMapping("CharSpace",
                new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_RETURN));
        inputManager
                .addMapping("CharShoot", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_SPACE));
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharLeft");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharRight");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharUp");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharDown");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharSpace");
        inputManager.addListener(this, "CharShoot");
    }

    private void createWall() {
        float xOff = -144;
        float zOff = -40;
        float startpt = bLength / 4 - xOff;
        float height = 6.1f;
        brick = new Box(Vector3f.ZERO, bLength, bHeight, bWidth);
        brick.scaleTextureCoordinates(new Vector2f(1f, .5f));
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                Vector3f vt = new Vector3f(i * bLength * 2 + startpt, bHeight
                        + height, zOff);
                addBrick(vt);
            }
            startpt = -startpt;
            height += 1.01f * bHeight;
        }
    }

    private void addBrick(Vector3f ori) {
        Geometry reBoxg = new Geometry("brick", brick);
        reBoxg.setMaterial(matBullet);
        reBoxg.setLocalTranslation(ori);
        reBoxg.addControl(new RigidBodyControl(1.5f));
        reBoxg.setShadowMode(ShadowMode.CastAndReceive);
        this.rootNode.attachChild(reBoxg);
        this.getPhysicsSpace().add(reBoxg);
    }

    private void prepareBullet() {
        bullet = new Sphere(32, 32, 0.4f, true, false);
        bullet.setTextureMode(TextureMode.Projected);
        bulletCollisionShape = new SphereCollisionShape(0.4f);
        matBullet = new Material(getAssetManager(),
                "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
        matBullet.setColor("Color", ColorRGBA.Green);
        // matBullet.setColor("m_GlowColor", ColorRGBA.Green);
        getPhysicsSpace().addCollisionListener(this);
    }

    private void prepareEffect() {
        int COUNT_FACTOR = 1;
        float COUNT_FACTOR_F = 1f;
        effect = new ParticleEmitter("Flame", Type.Triangle, 32 * COUNT_FACTOR);
        effect.setSelectRandomImage(true);
        effect.setStartColor(new ColorRGBA(1f, 0.4f, 0.05f,
                (float) (1f / COUNT_FACTOR_F)));
        effect.setEndColor(new ColorRGBA(.4f, .22f, .12f, 0f));
        effect.setStartSize(1.3f);
        effect.setEndSize(2f);
        effect.setShape(new EmitterSphereShape(Vector3f.ZERO, 1f));
        effect.setParticlesPerSec(0);
        effect.setGravity(0, -5, 0);
        effect.setLowLife(.4f);
        effect.setHighLife(.5f);
        effect.setInitialVelocity(new Vector3f(0, 7, 0));
        effect.setVelocityVariation(1f);
        effect.setImagesX(2);
        effect.setImagesY(2);
        Material mat = new Material(assetManager,
                "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Particle.j3md");
        mat.setTexture("Texture",
                assetManager.loadTexture("Effects/Explosion/flame.png"));
        effect.setMaterial(mat);
        // effect.setLocalScale(100);
        rootNode.attachChild(effect);
    }

    private void createLight() {
        Vector3f direction = new Vector3f(-0.1f, -0.7f, -1).normalizeLocal();
        DirectionalLight dl = new DirectionalLight();
        dl.setDirection(direction);
        dl.setColor(new ColorRGBA(1f, 1f, 1f, 1.0f));
        rootNode.addLight(dl);
    }

    private void createSky() {
        rootNode.attachChild(SkyFactory.createSky(assetManager,
                "Textures/Sky/Bright/BrightSky.dds", false));
    }

    private void createTerrain2() {
        matRock = new Material(assetManager,
                "Common/MatDefs/Terrain/TerrainLighting.j3md");
        matRock.setBoolean("useTriPlanarMapping", false);
        matRock.setBoolean("WardIso", true);
        matRock.setTexture("AlphaMap",
                assetManager.loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/alphamap.png"));
        Texture heightMapImage = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/mountains512.png");
        Texture grass = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/grass.jpg");
        grass.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        matRock.setTexture("DiffuseMap", grass);
        matRock.setFloat("DiffuseMap_0_scale", 64);
        Texture dirt = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/dirt.jpg");
        dirt.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        matRock.setTexture("DiffuseMap_1", dirt);
        matRock.setFloat("DiffuseMap_1_scale", 16);
        Texture rock = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/road.jpg");
        rock.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        matRock.setTexture("DiffuseMap_2", rock);
        matRock.setFloat("DiffuseMap_2_scale", 128);
        Texture normalMap0 = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/grass_normal.jpg");
        normalMap0.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        Texture normalMap1 = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/dirt_normal.png");
        normalMap1.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        Texture normalMap2 = assetManager
                .loadTexture("Textures/Terrain/splat/road_normal.png");
        normalMap2.setWrap(WrapMode.Repeat);
        matRock.setTexture("NormalMap", normalMap0);
        matRock.setTexture("NormalMap_1", normalMap2);
        matRock.setTexture("NormalMap_2", normalMap2);

        AbstractHeightMap heightmap = null;
        try {
            heightmap = new ImageBasedHeightMap(heightMapImage.getImage(),
                    0.25f);
            heightmap.load();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        terrain = new TerrainQuad("terrain", 65, 513, heightmap.getHeightMap());
        List<Camera> cameras = new ArrayList<Camera>();
        cameras.add(getCamera());
        TerrainLodControl control = new TerrainLodControl(terrain, cameras);
        terrain.addControl(control);
        terrain.setMaterial(matRock);
        terrain.setLocalScale(new Vector3f(2, 2, 2));

        terrainPhysicsNode = new RigidBodyControl(
                CollisionShapeFactory.createMeshShape(terrain), 0);
        terrain.addControl(terrainPhysicsNode);
        rootNode.attachChild(terrain);
        getPhysicsSpace().add(terrainPhysicsNode);
    }

    private void createTerrain() {


         assetManager.registerLocator("town.zip", ZipLocator.class);
         sceneModel = assetManager.loadModel("main.scene");
        //sceneModel = assetManager.loadModel("Scenes/ManyLights/Main.scene");
        sceneModel.setLocalScale(2f);
        //initFloor();
        // We set up collision detection for the scene by creating a
        // compound collision shape and a static RigidBodyControl with mass
        // zero.
        CollisionShape sceneShape = CollisionShapeFactory
                .createMeshShape((Node) sceneModel);
        landscape = new RigidBodyControl(sceneShape, 0);
        sceneModel.addControl(landscape);
        List<Camera> cameras = new ArrayList<Camera>();
        cameras.add(getCamera());
        rootNode.attachChild(sceneModel);
    }

    private void createCharacters() {
        CapsuleCollisionShape capsule = new CapsuleCollisionShape(3f, 4f);
        character = new CharacterControl(capsule, 0.01f);
        model = (Node) assetManager.loadModel("Models/Ninja/Ninja.mesh.xml");
        float scale = 0.25f;
        model.scale(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
        model.addControl(character);
        character.setPhysicsLocation(new Vector3f(0, -0.09f, 0));
        model.setShadowMode(ShadowMode.CastAndReceive);
        character.setViewDirection(new Vector3f(1, 0, 0));
        rootNode.attachChild(model);
        getPhysicsSpace().add(character);

        //BlenderKey blenderKey = new BlenderKey("Models/Oto/Oto.mesh.xml");

        //Spatial man = (Spatial) assetManager.loadModel(blenderKey);
        //man.setLocalTranslation(new Vector3f(-140, 12.5f, -10));

        // man.setShadowMode(ShadowMode.CastAndReceive);
        //rootNode.attachChild(man);

    }

    private void setupChaseCamera() {
        flyCam.setEnabled(false);
        chaseCam = new ChaseCamera(cam, model, inputManager);
    }

    private void setupAnimationController() {
        animationControl = model.getControl(AnimControl.class);
        animationControl.addListener(this);
        animationChannel = animationControl.createChannel();
        // shootingChannel = animationControl.createChannel();
        // shootingChannel.addBone(animationControl.getSkeleton().getBone(
        // "uparm.right"));
        // shootingChannel.addBone(animationControl.getSkeleton().getBone(
        // "arm.right"));
        // shootingChannel.addBone(animationControl.getSkeleton().getBone(
        // "hand.right"));
    }

    @Override
    public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {
        Vector3f camDir = cam.getDirection().clone().multLocal(0.1f);
        Vector3f camLeft = cam.getLeft().clone().multLocal(0.1f);
        camDir.y = 0;
        camLeft.y = 0;
        walkDirection.set(0, 0, 0);
        if (left) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camLeft);
        }
        if (right) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camLeft.negate());
        }
        if (up) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camDir);
        }
        if (down) {
            walkDirection.addLocal(camDir.negate());
        }
        if (!character.onGround()) {
            airTime = airTime + tpf;
        } else {
            airTime = 0;
        }
        if (walkDirection.length() == 0) {
            if (!"Idle1".equals(animationChannel.getAnimationName())) {
                animationChannel.setAnim("Idle1", 1f);
            }
        } else {
            character.setViewDirection(walkDirection);
            if (airTime > .3f) {
                if (!"stand".equals(animationChannel.getAnimationName())) {
                    animationChannel.setAnim("stand");
                }
            } else if (!"Walk".equals(animationChannel.getAnimationName())) {
                animationChannel.setAnim("Walk", 0.7f);
            }
        }
        character.setWalkDirection(walkDirection);
    }

    public void onAction(String binding, boolean value, float tpf) {
        if (binding.equals("CharLeft")) {
            if (value) {
                left = true;
            } else {
                left = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("CharRight")) {
            if (value) {
                right = true;
            } else {
                right = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("CharUp")) {
            if (value) {
                up = true;
            } else {
                up = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("CharDown")) {
            if (value) {
                down = true;
            } else {
                down = false;
            }
        } else if (binding.equals("CharSpace")) {
            character.jump();
        } else if (binding.equals("CharShoot") && !value) {
            bulletControl();
        }
    }

    private void bulletControl() {
        shootingChannel.setAnim("Dodge", 0.1f);
        shootingChannel.setLoopMode(LoopMode.DontLoop);
        Geometry bulletg = new Geometry("bullet", bullet);
        bulletg.setMaterial(matBullet);
        bulletg.setShadowMode(ShadowMode.CastAndReceive);
        bulletg.setLocalTranslation(character.getPhysicsLocation().add(
                cam.getDirection().mult(5)));
        RigidBodyControl bulletControl = new BombControl(bulletCollisionShape,
                1);
        bulletControl.setCcdMotionThreshold(0.1f);
        bulletControl.setLinearVelocity(cam.getDirection().mult(80));
        bulletg.addControl(bulletControl);
        rootNode.attachChild(bulletg);
        getPhysicsSpace().add(bulletControl);
    }

    public void collision(PhysicsCollisionEvent event) {
        if (event.getObjectA() instanceof BombControl) {
            final Spatial node = event.getNodeA();
            effect.killAllParticles();
            effect.setLocalTranslation(node.getLocalTranslation());
            effect.emitAllParticles();
        } else if (event.getObjectB() instanceof BombControl) {
            final Spatial node = event.getNodeB();
            effect.killAllParticles();
            effect.setLocalTranslation(node.getLocalTranslation());
            effect.emitAllParticles();
        }
    }

    public void onAnimCycleDone(AnimControl control, AnimChannel channel,
            String animName) {
        if (channel == shootingChannel) {
            channel.setAnim("stand");
        }
    }

    public void onAnimChange(AnimControl control, AnimChannel channel,
            String animName) {
    }

    // Load an image from the net, making sure it has already been
    // loaded when the method returns
    public Image loadPicture(String imageName) {
        return null;
    }

    // Load and play a sound from /usr/local/hacks/sounds/

    public void playSound(String name) {
        URL u = null;

        try {
            u = new URL("file:" + "/usr/local/hacks/sounds/" + name + ".au");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        }

        AudioClip a = Applet.newAudioClip(u);
        a.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: because it's his superpower ? xD just kidding i couldn't resist sorry ^^

Comment: that's ok, just use my questions for your personal fun now that I've solved the problem with the guy floating in the air like he was a superhero. I agree he looks a bit like a superhero so I might make this bug a feature so stay tuned.

Comment: very cool :) good luck with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this is due to this line of code:

```
CapsuleCollisionShape capsule = new CapsuleCollisionShape(3f, 4f);
```

and then you are scaling down the model. I dont know what the values passed in are, but i suppose one is a radius and the other one is a height, try moving down that 3f and that 4f to something lower, like 1.0f and 2.0f.

It seems the collision detection is pushing your character upwards because its collision shape is a capsule, which is of a different size than the model, and the model is placed in the middle of the capsule.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had to do a `CapsuleCollisionShape capsule = new CapsuleCollisionShape(0.0f, 0.0f);` and it works.

Comment: Thats great. this might be caused because the capsule is atacched to the characters feet. There should be a command to reposition it or even display the capsule. I will read some of the stuff you tagged so i can get more knowledge on the sdks you are using. I love game development and am looking forward to see your result. Keep on!

Comment: Many thanks! The example I'm taking stuff from is http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:walking_character and I've now managed to get the Ninja going just as well as Oto the robot was in the examples so it's fixed that the main char can walk properly and I'm reading in the Quake example scene so that I don't have to build a scene from physics objects. I'm going to update to question with where the character is supposed to walk which now is solved by doing negate on the vector since the char is facing the opposite of Oto. I'm updating this question with a screenshot how it looks